# Ubuntu + Opera (ipv6 issue)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipv6, opera

Did anyone manage to get Opera working on Ubuntu 9.04?

It's trying to resole domain names in IPv6 way, and somehow gets a zero-reply from the gateway (ip-address of much zeroes), and fails to connect.

UPD: wireshark sniff:

```
8  5.647832    192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 DNS Standard query A google.com
9   5.649655    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 DNS Standard query response A 1.0.0.0
```

By the way, ALL other networking goes fine, including firefox.

One solution i found was to disable IPv6 in kernel, but in 9.04 it's impossible due to a BUG.

Can i have Opera working without rebuilding the kernel with a patch?

**UPD:** if I `ping` some host (so its IP is cached now) - Opera finds it, and opens the page OK. Maybe, there's a way to "pre-ping" everything Opera tries to connect to? :))

Comment: The bug in question: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/351656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

```
$ opera -debugdns
...
dns: Host 'google.com' resolved to 1.0.0.0
```

This is a typical malformed response from the broken DNS implementation found
on some routers. Opera first looks for ipv6, and gets the wrong reply.

The solution is to point resolv.conf to OpenDNS's DNS servers - 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220. Now my resolv.conf looks like this:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 2):

If your NAT router is also acting as a DNS server there have been known issues with IPv6 (AAAA) resolution in many cases.

I can say that I run Opera (v9.63 & 10 beta) on a Debian machine pointing to a BIND resolver and native IPv6 and it all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

"gets a zero-reply from the gateway" from your DNS server you mean ? If you dns server reply with an nul IPv6 address to AAAA request you probably have a problem on your DNS server !

Comment: I probably have a problem with my router :))
But i've read a plenty of forums where people complained they've the same problem, so i guess that's not correct

Comment: I saw your edit, this ip an IPv4 resolution query, the DNS server of your router is just bugged, what kind of router is it ?

Comment: It's Paradyne 6212. Not a fresh one :)
Despite, as Andrew said, all browsers (and other network software!) work just OK, only Opera works wierd

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat, opera installs, and loads, and does not connect to the net. !? Firefox ok, Epiphany ok, Thunderbird ok, Seamonkey ok, ...

Comment: I believe we should either recompile Linux Kernel without the IPv6 module, or wait for opera update :)

Comment: Solved! Look here :)

Answer (score 0):

I've read much about that, and it seems to be a bug in 9.04 distribution. You'll have to recompile the kernel without ipv6 in order to do it.

Comment: This is a bug in opera, *not* 9.04. There is a bug in 9.04 (the inability to disable IPv6). Opera should however work fine with v6 enabled.

Comment: Alas, it works not :( A new Opera release is coming, i'm curious to see whether it works :)

Comment: Already: download Opera 10, http://www.opera.com/

Comment: Nah, the same problem :) But solved, see above

Answer (score 0):

The -debugdns switch tells me that for example ipv6.google.com is doing an IPv4 lookup first, and gets resource temporarily unavailable from gethostbyname.  Hmmmm...would hope it would look up IPv6 first.  Firefox goes right to it, and works OK.  Sigh...there must be some bits somewhere I could change or set up to ask Opera to do an IPv6 query first.  Heck...there's even an IPv6 address as the first nameserver line in my resolv.conf.  My Linux router does an IPv6 tunnel, BIND, and most everything else needed for v6 connectivity.